# InfoPath 2007 Template in InfoPath 2010, PDF Export is having Bad Quality and Alignment

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, pdf

I'm working on InfoPath 2007 template within InfoPath 2010.  When I export the form to PDF and when I open the PDF, the quality and alignment is very bad.

Is there any way to force the template to export using "CutePDF writer" because "CutePDF writer" yields me good and perfect output?

**Note:**

A. I'm exporting the form using the below code,

`Export(filename,pdf);`

B. I'm not using InfoPath web browsable forms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set CutePDF as the Printer on the Page Setup tab of View's properties then print the view instead of exporting.

Comment: how to do it programmatically.?